# Find string with regular expression in python

Tags: python, regex

I am a newbie in python and I am trying to cut piece of string in another string at python. 
I looked at other similar questions but I could not find my answer.

I have a variable which contain a domain list which the domains look like this :

http://92.230.38.21/ios/Channel767/Hotbird.mp3
http://92.230.38.21/ios/Channel9798/Coldbird.mp3

....

I want the mp3 file name (in this example Hotbird, Coldbird etc)

I know I must be able to do it with re.findall() but I have no idea about regular expressions I need to use.

Any idea?

Update:
Here is the part I used:

```
    for final in match2:
         netname=re.findall('\W+\//\W+\/\W+\/\W+\/\W+', final)
         print final
         print netname
```

Which did not work.  Then  I tried to do this one which only cut the ip address (92.230.28.21) but not the name:

```
    for final in match2:
         netname=re.findall('\d+\.\d+\.\d+\.\d+', final)
         print final
```

Comment: Can you show any of the code you have already tried?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You may just use [`str.split()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.split):

```
>>> urls = ["http://92.230.38.21/ios/Channel767/Hotbird.mp3", "http://92.230.38.21/ios/Channel9798/Coldbird.mp3"]
>>> for url in urls:
...     print(url.split("/")[-1].split(".")[0])
... 
Hotbird
Coldbird
```

And here is an example regex-based approach:

```
>>> import re
>>>
>>> pattern = re.compile(r"/(\w+)\.mp3$")
>>> for url in urls:
...     print(pattern.search(url).group(1))
... 
Hotbird
Coldbird
```

where we are using a capturing group `(\w+)` to capture the mp3 filename consisting of one or more aplhanumeric characters which is followed by a dot, `mp3` at the end of the url.

Answer (score 0):

How about ?

([^/]*mp3)$

I think that might work

Basically it says...

Match from the end of the line, start with mp3, then match everything back to the first slash.

Think it will perform well.